# Unable to create notebook kernel, as you have reached the maximum of 10

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I have opened a notebook on the Bluemix Spark service (Enterprise Plan) and received the following error message:

[image]

What does this error mean?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but do you have 10 active notebooks in you service instance where, the kernels are still active, they are marked with green circle, just try to stop them and see if that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already 10 Notebook kernels running at the same time. You need to stop one to start a new one:

On the Notebooks list (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/data/analytics), find 
Notebooks with a green circle (those are notebooks with a running Kernel). Then, click on the gear icon of such a notebook, and choose "Stop Kernel".

Reason: Kernels may continue running even if you close a notebook's user interface if there is still code being executed. In that case, you need to explicitly “Stop Kernel" as described.